# Persistence file operations in background

Tags: android, android-background

Currently I'm developing a persistence library for Android in Kotlin. Now I am at the point where I've to handle  file operations (read, write, etc.) and I wonder what is the best way to do this? First I don't have to do this on the main thread to block the UI. Second I have to be sure that all operations are executed immediately and no one gets lost at process kills or device restarts.

I looked at the [background guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) on the developer site but now I am a bit confused. As I don't want to start a forground service for each persist operation it looks like [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) is the best solution for me. The documentation states:

> WorkManager is intended for tasks that are deferrable - that is, not required to run immediately - and required to run reliably even if the app exits or the device restarts.

But here is the problem: My work should be executed immediately and does not depend on system events so I am not sure if this is the best way to go. What do you thing is the best solution for me?

Comment: "I am at the point where I've to handle file operations" -- what is the trigger for the file operations? Are these in response to user input?

Comment: Yeah they are. It can be done from code as well. It's actually a reimplementation of [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Comment: "It can be done from code as well" -- they are all done from code. For I/O triggered by user input, use your preferred background threading solution: Kotlin coroutines, RxJava, `LiveData` and an `Executor`, etc.

Comment: But how do I make sure when using `LiveData` for example that it is not killed when the user closes the app or the system destroys my process?

Comment: If the work is triggered by user input, it is unlikely that your process will be terminated while your I/O is in progress, unless the I/O is huge. In that case, use a service, possibly needing to be a foreground service if it will run longer than a minute.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to do it with Kotlin coroutines? It's clear to use the IO dispatcher but which context should I use for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a repository expose `suspend` functions that handle the I/O. Here is a `TextRepository` that reads and writes text from a `Uri` (as this is adapted from a future book sample that supports files and Storage Access Framework `Uri` values):

```
class TextRepository(context: Context) {
  private val resolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver

  suspend fun read(source: Uri) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
      resolver.openInputStream(source)?.use { stream ->
        StreamResult.Content(source, stream.readText())
      } ?: throw IllegalStateException("could not open $source")
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
      StreamResult.Content(source, "")
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
      StreamResult.Error(t)
    }
  }

  suspend fun write(source: Uri, text: String): StreamResult =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      try {
        resolver.openOutputStream(source)?.use { stream ->
          stream.writeText(text)
          StreamResult.Content(source, text)
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("could not open $source")
      } catch (t: Throwable) {
        StreamResult.Error(t)
      }
    }
}

private fun InputStream.readText(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): String =
  readBytes().toString(charset)

private fun OutputStream.writeText(
  text: String,
  charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8
): Unit = write(text.toByteArray(charset))

sealed class StreamResult {
  object Loading : StreamResult()
  data class Content(val source: Uri, val text: String) : StreamResult()
  data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : StreamResult()
}
```

In this case, I am using the loading-content-error (LCE) pattern, where the `suspend` functions are returning a `StreamResult`. `StreamResult.Content` wraps the read-in text or the text that was just written.

Then, you can have a `ViewModel` of some sort call the `suspend` functions:

```
class MainMotor(repo: TextRepository) : ViewModel {
  private val _results = MutableLiveData<StreamResult>()
  val results: LiveData<StreamResult> = _results

  fun read(source: Uri) {
    _results.value = StreamResult.Loading

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
      _results.value = repo.read(source)
    }
  }

  fun write(source: Uri, text: String) {
    _results.value = StreamResult.Loading

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
      _results.value = repo.write(source, text)
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, I route the `StreamResult` unmodified through a `MutableLiveData` for the UI to consume, following an MVI-style pattern. In practice, a `ViewModel` probably transforms the repo result into something more directly usable by the UI, and so the `LiveData` would be of some other type, with the `ViewModel` performing the conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot! One more question: Since I write a library which is a reimplementation of `SharedPreferences` my objects are not related to an `Activity`. Can I still use a `ViewModel` then?

Comment: @Cilenco: Probably not. Off the cuff, and IMHO, your library should expose `suspend` functions that your clients would launch.